# Keeping two adjacent elements side-by-side as though they're in the same <tr>?

Tags: css

This is likely impossible but I figured I'd ask in case someone has a solution. This is my HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <label>Label One</label>
    <span>Span One</span>
    <label>Label Two</label>
    <span>Span Two</span>
    <!-- Many more pairs of <label> & <span> -->
</div>
```

Unfortunately I can't add any JS or alter the HTML, I can only change the CSS! Each `<label>`/`<span>` pair should never be separated and should behave as though they're `<td>`'s inside of a `<tr>`. Currently they're `display:inline-block`, so they look the way they should unless, for instance, Span One was very long and Span Two gets knocked down on its own line - Label Two should go down with Span Two in that case. I'm wondering if maybe there's a value for `display` that could stop the pairs from being split...

**EDIT:** To be clear, the pairs need to be side-by-side on the same line, until there's no more width to the container - then the next pair should drop down, as though it's a single element, to the next line.

**EDIT2:** Floating doesn't seem to work right because each `<label>` and `<span>` has a background color, and if the `<span>` is too long and wraps to the next line, the `<label>` needs to match its height.

Comment: Have you tried using a "float:left" on a "label" block in the CSS?  The obvious downside would be that ALL lebels would float left.  But it's a start.

Comment: Float would not work since they will wrap if the content is too long

Comment: Yeah the whole issue is that the pairs are being split up. I think I also neglected to mention that the pairs need to be shown side by side! My bad guys!

Comment: I don't think this is doable using only css

Comment: Logically/structurally, assuming that label's content and span's content are always related to each other, it would make sense for each pair to be encapsulated in some sort of element. It's a shame that you have no control over the HTML.

Comment: Basically OP wants each pair of label and span to behave like 2 table cells in the same table row. I do not think this is achievable with only css

Comment: @Crush Post that as an answer. I want to upvote it.

Comment: @tylerl can the elements have a % width? If so then it can be done easily

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Funny - I meant `<div class="container">`... Unfortunately the length of each label/span is unpredictable. I'm thinking this probably is impossible, which makes sense since the HTML (or non-HTML...) wasn't made with my design in mind. Time to change the design - thanks guys!

Comment: It’s unclear whether the appearance should be *tabular*. The title suggests it should. Then there does not seem to be any CSS solution. If you just want to control line breaking, the odds are better (there is probably no perfect solution, but a good enough solution, with floating). Please clarify the question by editing the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ([**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/GceDp/)). It allows the elements to sit side-by-side and forces the second element onto the next line if the first element is too long (try uncommenting the border style on the jsfiddle to see how it is reorganizing the elements).

```
label { display: block; float: left; }
span { display: block; }
span:after { clear: both; }
```

Comment: He wants the pairs to sit inline until they need to wrap, but your solution will always force the next pair to the next line, even if there is room for them on the current line. PS you don't need to specify display: block if you float an element. Floated elements are forced to block level.